How to solve the recurrence relation $a_n=\sqrt{a_{n-2}}$
I don't exactly remember where I got this from or when, but I remember seeing this recurrence relation in a Youtube video that was just going over the different types of recurrence relations.
I have been trying to solve this off and on for probably the last 6 months, and I'm not exactly sure on how to solve it. Here is my (best) attempt at solving this:
We have that$$a_n=\sqrt{a_{n-2}}\implies a_{n-2}=\sqrt{a_{n-4}}=a_{n-4}^{1/2}\\\implies a_n=\sqrt{(\sqrt{a_{n-4}})}=a_{n-4}^{1/4}$$Now, we can see that$$a_n=a_{n-0}^{1/2^0}=a_{n-2}^{1/2^1}=a_{n-4}^{1/2^2}$$which we can rewrite as$$a_n=a_{n-0}^{2^{-0}}=a_{n-2}^{2^{-1}}=a_{n-4}^{2^{-2}}\\a_n=a_{n-0}^{2^{-0/2}}=a_{n-2}^{2^{-2/2}}=a_{n-4}^{2^{-4/2}}$$so now my goal here was to find some constant $c$ that satisfied$$c^{2^{-x/2}}=\sqrt{c^{2^{1-(x/2)}}}$$but it seems like no matter what type of manipulation I perform on this, I always get that the RHS and LHS are equivalent, so my question is:

What am I doing wrong when solving this recurrence relation, and how do I solve it?


if you set $a_0=k$, you have that $a_2=\sqrt k$, $a_4=k^{1/4}$ and so on

With $\log$ the sequence can be recast as $L_n = \frac 12 L_{n-2}$

@Cesareo Thanks, I think I understand where my confusion comes from. I'll post a self-answer.

Taking the $\ln$ of my recurrence relation, as pointed out by Cesareo, we get$$L_n=\frac12L_{n-2}$$which can be rearranged as$$L_n-\frac12L_{n-2}=0$$and has characteristic equation$$\lambda^2-\frac12=0\\\implies\lambda=\pm\frac{\sqrt2}2=\pm2^{-1/2}$$so we have that$$L_n=c_0(2^{-1/2})^n+c_1(-2^{-1/2})^n\\=c_02^{-n/2}+c_1(-1)^n(2^{-n/2})\\=2^{-n/2}(c_0+c_1(-1)^n)$$and now since we have that$$L_n=\ln(a_n)$$the solution to this recurrence relation is$$a_n=e^{2^{-n/2}(c_0+c_1(-1)^n)}$$I think that the confusion came from the fact that I needed to rearrange the terms somehow so that I could solve this using ordinary techniques, however I just failed to realize how exactly I should go about doing that.
